# jpa one-to-many data insertion error in java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0

forum member I am having one problem with the insertion of data using Hibernate JPA framework.

I am having one-to-many relationship between task and resources.

my task model is like below shown code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
public class Task {

    private Integer id;
    private Set<Employee> employee = new HashSet<Employee>(0);

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch =FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "task_employee", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "taskid") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "employeeid") })
    public Set<Employee> getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Set<Employee> employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }


}
```

and my Employee model is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    private Integer id;
    private String firstname;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

}
```

I am able to insert the record successfully when the

**1. Task id is 1 and employeeid is 1,**

**2. Task id is 1 and employeeid is 2,**

**3. Task id is 2 and employeeid is 3,**

but the error occurs when the employee id is duplicated like below insertion.

**4. Task id is 1 and employeeid is 1**

**it gives me error**

```
79512 [http-8080-4] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
79517 [http-8080-4] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Duplicate entry '2' for key 'employeeid'
79517 [http-8080-4] ERROR org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

**What's wrong with my code? Please, help me!!!**

Comment: Your 4th record is taskId is 1 and emp Id is 1 which is same as 1st record. Can you post the data insertion code?

Comment: And full stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a OneToMany relation ship.  This mean a task can have many employee, but a single employee can have only on task!

> error occurs when the employee id is duplicated

But you violated (or tryed to violate) the second part of that constraint

So you should use a ManyToMany relation ship.